# Testing a complex API in jest

Tags: javascript, express, unit-testing, jestjs

I have made a REST API that looks like below:

```
async function chooseTheFeature(){
 
}
exports.MyAPI = async(req, res, next) => {
  //Get request body here
  try{
    await chooseTheFeature(req.body);
  //If we don't receive any error, we send 200 as response
  res.status(200).json({message:"All went well!"});
  }
  catch(e){
  res.status(400).json({message:"Something went wrong!"});
  }
```

I have routes.js file:

```
//importing MyAPI function here
app.get('/my-api',MyAPI);
```

The `chooseThefeature` function is so complex that it calls almost 20 different functions which in turn call many other functions each. Basically many tasks like files updates, mainframe processing and DB updates happen in all these function.

Now my task is to create a unit test case in `jest` for this API. I have little knowledge on `jest` so I am struggling to find correct approach to write test case for it. One thing that I know for sure is that we don't have to call this API in reality in our test case. We have to mock its functionality, but how do I do that is a big question for me. Another problem is that `chooseTheFeature` function does not returns anything, so it is a bit difficult to mock it through jest.

Can anyone help me to find correct approach to write a suitable test case in this scenario?

Thanks!

Comment: It's a little difficult to say which is the right way to test your function without knowing what the function does. But based on what you said the first thing I thought when I read "that function is so complex" is that you should break it in smaller pieces and avoid large procedures. I think the right approach is to concieve your test at the same time you write your code, or even before writing code (like TDD).

Comment: Totally agree with your point. But isn't there any escape now?

Comment: I couldn't say without seeing the function, but procedural code tends to be quite untestable..

Comment: First of all, what do you want to test? The controller or the `chooseTheFeature` function?